# Max Query Over Partition

Tags: sql

I want to select max values related to query, but all results are coming. Any idea ?

QUERY

```
SELECT MAXRecID,MAXSetID,MAXRID,PreReifiedValue,ComplianceState
FROM v_CI_CurrentComplianceStatus as A
INNER JOIN v_CIRules as B
ON B.CI_ID = A.CI_ID
INNER JOIN v_R_System  as C
ON C.ResourceID = A.ItemKey
INNER JOIN 
 ( SELECT PreReifiedValue,setting_CI_ID,
      MAX(RecordID) AS MAXRecID,
      MAX(SettingID) AS MAXSetID,
      MAX(RuleID) AS MAXRID
   FROM CI_CurrentRuleDetail
   GROUP BY PreReifiedValue,Setting_CI_ID,instancedata
 ) AS D
ON D.Setting_CI_ID = A.CI_ID
GROUP by MAXRecID,MAXSetID,MAXRID,PreReifiedValue,rulename,ComplianceState
```

Results

```
MAXRecID            MAXSetID    MAXRID  PreReifiedValue ComplianceState
72057594038117564   16780566    16780622    10                2
72057594038117565   16780570    16780620     0                2
```

Comment: I don't know what you actually want as a result but you got an extra column in your final `GROUP BY`. When you remove `rulename` it's equivalent to `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Simple rule: when no aggregate functions are involved, do SELECT DISTINCT instead of GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
    SELECT 
       MAX(tmp.MAXRecID), MAX(tmp.MAXSetID), MAX(tmp.MAXRID), MAX(tmp.PreReifiedValue), MAX(tmp.ComplianceState)
    FROM (
    SELECT MAXRecID,MAXSetID,MAXRID,PreReifiedValue,ComplianceState
    FROM v_CI_CurrentComplianceStatus as A
    INNER JOIN v_CIRules as B
    ON B.CI_ID = A.CI_ID
    INNER JOIN v_R_System  as C
    ON C.ResourceID = A.ItemKey
    INNER JOIN 
     ( SELECT PreReifiedValue,setting_CI_ID,
          MAX(RecordID) AS MAXRecID,
          MAX(SettingID) AS MAXSetID,
          MAX(RuleID) AS MAXRID
       FROM CI_CurrentRuleDetail
       GROUP BY PreReifiedValue,Setting_CI_ID,instancedata
     ) AS D
    ON D.Setting_CI_ID = A.CI_ID
    ) AS tmp
    GROUP by tmp.MAXRecID, tmp.MAXSetID, tmp.MAXRID, tmp.PreReifiedValue, tmp.rulename, tmp.ComplianceState
```

Comment: Thanks, received; Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
Invalid column name 'rulename'.

Comment: I don't know what is rulename, but if you add 'rulename' after select in inner select, i think you solve error. @Ellefson

Comment: No luck, 342 rows are coming instead of 2